# How to pass variables from Python to Mathematica?

Tags: scripting, python

I have a Mathematica code that I want to run via Python using subprocess. The Mathematica code contains two variables that I want to pass through Python.

However, when I tried to do that, I always got the error which says 'Variable' was not found.

```py
import numpy as np
import math

def initial(th, ph):
    return math.cos(th/2), complex(math.cos(ph), math.sin(ph))*math.sin(th/2) 

alpha, beta = initial(2,0)

import subprocess

def run_mathematica_script(phys_alpha, phys_beta):
    # Create a string with the Mathematica code to set the arb variable
    #arb_str = f"arb = {arb_values};"
    phys_alpha = round((phys_alpha.real),3)
    phys_beta = round((phys_beta.real),3)
    subprocess.run(["Mathematica","-c", "/home/address/the/T_d.nb",str(phys_alpha),str(phys_beta)],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Calculate alpha and beta using the initial function
    alpha_i, beta_i = initial(2, 0)
    phys_alpha = alpha_i.real
    phys_beta = beta_i.real
   
    run_mathematica_script(phys_alpha,phys_beta)
```

where `phys_alpha` and `phys_beta` are the variables which I want to pass to Mathematica through the Python code:
Here is how I defined my variables in Mathematica:

```
physalpha = ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine[[3]]];
physbeta = ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine[[4]]];
Print[physalpha];
Print[physbeta];
arb = {{physalpha}, {physbeta}};
```

Comment: Can you please include the exact error you get? Also, you should probably use [`wolframscript`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/RunWolframLanguageCodeFromTheCommandLine.html), and not use Notebook (.nb) but a simple script text file (.m or .wls).

Comment: I got exactly that error: "0.87 file was not found". HOwever, 0.87 is not a file. It is the variable which I want to pass to Mathematica from Python

Comment: try https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/